# Flutter error request "PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path "

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an application to take photos of an alert from the phone's camera and display it in the application. The part works well. I also added a dart button to send. When you click on last, the application must then send to an API: the location, the extension of the image and an alert. Unfortunately, when you click the submit button, an error occurs.

[image: error]

**My code**

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(33, 150, 243, 1),
        onPressed: () async {
          currentPosition = await _getCurrentPosition();

          if (selectedItem != null) {
            String geoPointer = currentPosition != null
                ? '(${currentPosition!.latitude}, ${currentPosition!.longitude})'
                : '';
            final List<String> imagePaths =
                images.map((file) => '"${file.path}"').toList();

            fetchAlerteApi(selectedItem!, imagePaths, geoPointer)
                .then((response) {
              print('Réponse de l\'API : $response');
            }).catchError((error) {
              print('API Erreur : $error');
            });
          } else {
            print(
                'Aucun élément sélectionné');
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_right_alt,
          size: 32,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
```

The API should retrieve the image in binary

**API code**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchAlerteApi(
  String typeAlertes,
  List<String> imagePaths, 
  String geoPointer,
) async {
  try {
    List<String> imageBytesList = [];

   
    for (String imagePath in imagePaths) {
      String imageName = imagePath.split('/').last;
      print("++++ $imageName ++++");

      Uint8List imageBytes = await File(imagePath).readAsBytes();
      String baseimage = base64Encode(imageBytes);
      imageBytesList.add(baseimage);
    }

    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'type_alerte': typeAlertes,
      'images': imageBytesList,
      'geo_pointer': geoPointer,
    };

    final Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://enika.afriklabtech.com/api/alertes/create'),
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonEncode(data),
    );

    // Gestion de la réponse ici...

    if (response.statusCode == 301 || response.statusCode == 302) {
      // Si c'est une redirection permanente, suivez-la
      final redirectUrl = response.headers['location'];
      if (redirectUrl != null) {
        final redirectResponse = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(redirectUrl),
          headers: headers,
          body: jsonEncode(data),
        );
        return jsonDecode(redirectResponse.body);

      } else {
        throw Exception(
            'La redirection ne contient pas d\'URL de destination.');
      }

    } else if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return responseData;
    } else {
      throw Exception('failed'); 
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error request: $e'); 
    rethrow; 
  }
}
```

[image: API]